# ElasticSearch gem method to scan all documents in index

Tags: elasticsearch

I am upgrading our ElasticSearch server to the latest (v1.0.1) and in the process using the new [ElasticSearch gem](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails) and removing the Tire gem.

Tire had a [scan](http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/l/load_balanced_tire-0.1/Tire/Search/Scan.html) method (that mapped to the [scan type search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html))to iterate over all documents in the index and I am looking to see if someone knows of a similar method/attribute in the new ElasticSearch rails gem that can walk over all indexed documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch-rails gem has a dependency on [elasticsearch gem](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-ruby). This gem exposes the `search` api which takes `search_type` as an option, which could be `scan` for your case.

Also, `elasticsearch` gem has a `scroll` [api](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-ruby/blob/master/elasticsearch-api/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/scroll.rb), that you can use as well.